# Bash - paste the content of a file after a line containing a given string

Tags: bash

Thank you very much in advance for helping!

I have a long file named source.xml
I'd like to make a bash script to insert the content of 2 xml files (see their name and url below) inside source.xml substituting the following two lines:

```
<include url="%SWFPATH%/scenes/corrugated_external/corrugated_cement_sheets/index.xml"/>
<include url="%SWFPATH%/scenes/corrugated_external/defining_asbestos/index.xml"/>
```

Because I need to run the script through dozens of directories, I cannot really specify any folder name.
I think the best way to approach this is:

1- Merging both index.xml files in one (I already have done this)

2- Insert that merged file before or after a line containing 'include'

3- Delete any line containing 'include' (I know how to do this)

How can achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Does it have to be done in Bash?

Answer (score 2):

Something along the lines of:

```
sed -e "/<include url=.../r /path/to/corrugated_cement_sheets/index.xml" -e '/<include url=...>/d' source.xml
```

Ofcourse you must do this for the other one aswell and replace include url=... with the full string that you want to replace. In this case:

```
<include url="%SWFPATH%/scenes/corrugated_external/corrugated_cement_sheets/index.xml"/>
```

Comment: +1 - nice, but this also prints the `<include ...` line itself before the included file.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm afraid I can't use your suggestion. I'm going to run this script through dozens of files so I cannot specify the name of the folder name containing the index.xml file. I'll update my question giving more details... Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Although you can do this with standard text-based tools, I would recommend using an XML-aware tool such as [XMLStarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/). Why ?

1. it'll respect XML structure
2. it'll respect XML character and entity encodings